# Fortran array Index

Tags: c, arrays, fortran, fortran90

I am migrating the Fortran code to C. I would like to know what will be the C equivalent for the following statements
T is a 2d array of dimension `(B,B)` and `T_indices` is an array of indices in `T` , `T_indices(E)` where `E < B`. `Ai` and `Bi` are variables.

```
T(T_indices(:),:) = 1/(Ai/Bi)*T(T_indices(:),:)

T(:,T_indices(:)) = 1/(Ai/Bi)*T(:,T_indices(:))
```

My proposed C translation:

```
for (i=0 ; i < E ; i++){
 for (j=0 ; j< B ; j++){
  T[(T_indices[i]-1) * B + j] = 1/(Ai/Bi)* T[(T_indices[i]-1) * B + j];
  T[j * B + (T_indices[i]-1)] = 1/(Ai/Bi)* T[j * B + (T_indices[i]-1)];
 }
}
```

Is this a correct translation?

Comment: How is T declared in C? Is J supposed to be the same as j?

Comment: T float is single dim array of BxB , yes my mistake J is j

Comment: yes A and B are scalars , just for scaling the array . updated the question . thanks

Comment: If I remember from school, Fortran array subscripts are one based while c is zero based.  I also recall that Fortran uses column major ordering so you may have reverse the order of the subscripts.

Comment: You could always test your code using a simple example...

Comment: @JonTrauntvein as T is 1d array it is accessed as stride of B , so subscripts don't matter I believe.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it.. Why do you use `1/(Ai/Bi)`? Shouldn't that be `Bi/Ai` :-P

Comment: @AlexanderVogt     1/(Ai/Bi) is just going to be number I believe . it shouldn’t be effected with how we access the array

Comment: @JonTrauntvein There is not too much to reverse in the C 1D array... You can index it as you want, there are many codes which use column major ordering by hand in 1D arrays in C.

Comment: Since I haven't used Fortran since 1979, I, too, had to refresh my memory According to Programmer's Guide to Fortran 90, 3nd Edition, Chapter 4, Arrays, at http://www.fortran.com/fortran_storenew/Html/Info/books/gd3_c04_1.html. 4.1.3 Array Declarations, by default, array subscripts count from 1, which can be overridden by the declaration. So, assuming that you used the simplest valid array declarations, your array math looks right. With respect to row major versus row minor, assuming that the same program  initializes and manipulates the array, row and column ordering should be moot.

Comment: Row and column ordering is moot in this particular case because the overall operation performed is symmetric with respect to transposition of matrix `T`.  Supposing that the C program's `T_indices` holds exactly the same values that its Fortran analog holds, and barring any funny business with the applicable Fortran declarations, yes, the translation does look correct.